# suspend a deployment/replicaset to stop a CrashLooping Pod from looping

Tags: kubernetes

i have a pod that is in CrashLoopBackOff. the reason is clear, i will have to migrate a database-schema to fix that before the container may retry looping.

i understand that the pod is supposed to crash-loop but i need to pause this. if `kubectl rollout pause` and then `kubectl delete pod`, the pod is terminating and still the deployment's replicaset seems to start a new one.

is there any way to just "suspend the deployment or replicaset" to have a chance to repair infrastructure without the pods constantly loop-crashing and/or getting recreated?

Answer (score 2):

i just found out i have to scale the deployment's pod to 0 replicas:

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment/<your-pod>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54821044/how-to-stop-pause-a-pod-in-kubernetes